# Fill color dynamically in Canvas Cylinder I am getting error as max width undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

kindly bear with my english

I am working on creating (I am new to Canvas) Cylinder. Dynamically fill color when the user enter the percentage value in the text box for example 10% the cylinder fill for 10% like wise till 100%.

I have created cylinder, I have created the little validation for the text box when i tried to other value instead of %

here is my code for validation and Filling color

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#my_input").focusout(function(event) {
                        if($("#my_input").val().indexOf("%") != -1){

                        if($.isNumeric($("#my_input").val().replace('%',''))) {

                                // Allow only backspace and delete
                                if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37) {
                                    //$("#myCanvas").animate({ opacity: 0.25 });
                                }
                                else {
                                    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                                    if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                                        event.preventDefault(); 
                                    }   
                                }
                                perc =  parseInt($("#my_input").val().replace('%','')) / 100;
                                draw();                             
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                alert('Value in %');
                            }
                    });
                });
                function draw()
                {
                    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    var x = 180;
                    var y = 40;     
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.rect(x, y, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                    context.lineWidth = 7;

                    var per = perc;
                    if(per > 1)perc = 1;
                    // fill
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
                    context.rect(x, y, maxWidth * perc, maxHeight);
                    context.fill();
                }
```

Here is my HTML Code for canvas

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
```

Here is the code for Creating Cylinder

```
            <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        //the below is code is for to work RequestAnimationFrame (SVG) in all the browsers -- Mahadevan         
        (function() {
            var lastTime = 0;
            var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
            for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
                window.cancelAnimationFrame =
                  window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
            }

            if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
                window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
                    var currTime = new Date().getTime();
                    var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
                    var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
                      timeToCall);
                    lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
                    return id;
                };

            if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
                window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
                    clearTimeout(id);
                };
        }());
        //the below code is to generate Cylinder object -- Mahadevan
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var degreeAngle = 0;
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        function drawRotatedCylinder(x, y, w, h, degreeAngle) {
            context.save();
            context.translate(x + w / 10, y + h / 10);
            context.rotate(degreeAngle * Math.PI / 180);
            drawCylinder(-w / 10, -h / 10, w, h);
            context.restore();
        }
        function drawCylinder(x, y, w, h) {

            context.beginPath(); //to draw the top circle
            for (var i = 0 * Math.PI; i < 2 * Math.PI; i += 0.01) {

                xPos = (x + w / 2) - (w / 2 * Math.sin(i)) * Math.sin(0 * Math.PI) + (w / 2 * Math.cos(i)) * Math.cos(0 * Math.PI);

                yPos = (y + h / 8) + (h / 8 * Math.cos(i)) * Math.sin(0 * Math.PI) + (h / 8 * Math.sin(i)) * Math.cos(0 * Math.PI);

                if (i == 0) {
                    context.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
                } else {
                    context.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                }
            }
            context.moveTo(x, y + h / 8);
            context.lineTo(x, y + h - h / 8);

            for (var i = 0 * Math.PI; i < Math.PI; i += 0.01) {
                xPos = (x + w / 2) - (w / 2 * Math.sin(i)) * Math.sin(0 * Math.PI) + (w / 2 * Math.cos(i)) * Math.cos(0 * Math.PI);
                yPos = (y + h - h / 8) + (h / 8 * Math.cos(i)) * Math.sin(0 * Math.PI) + (h / 8 * Math.sin(i)) * Math.cos(0 * Math.PI);

                if (i == 0) {
                    context.moveTo(xPos, yPos);

                } else {
                    context.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                }
            }
            context.moveTo(x + w, y + h / 8);
            context.lineTo(x + w, y + h - h / 8);
            context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
            context.stroke();               
            context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
            context.fill();
        }

        function animate() {
            //requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            drawRotatedCylinder(100, 100, 180, 180, degreeAngle++);
        }


        //]]> 
        </script>
```

And here is my Final HTml Code

```
Numberic Value <input type ="text" id="my_input" class="numeric" name="my_input" placeholder="Enter value"/>
```

When i tried to enter the value in the textbox that cylinder canvas getting hidden and i am getting an error as Uncaught ReferenceError: maxWidth is not defined

When i checked for circle canvas in google it says i need to put (context.rect) instead of rect i need to put arc i tried putting that still it was not working.

Kindly help me for the above solution

Thanks & REgards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust the height of the cylinder, not the width... And should redraw the cylinder if you are clearing (clearRect) the canvas.

You can try with the following function:

```
function draw()
{
    maxWidth = 180;
    maxHeight = 140;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var x = 190;
    var y = 260;     

    var per = perc;
    if(per > 1)perc = 1;
    // fill
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.rect(x-maxWidth/2, y-maxHeight * perc, maxWidth, maxHeight * perc);
    context.fill();

    drawCylinder(100, 100, 180, 180);
}
```

Check working [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f2wZh/) ...